# Composition of holomorphic maps and normal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be smooth manifolds and
$$
X\xrightarrow{~f~}Y\xrightarrow{~g~}Z
$$
be two composable embeddings. One can consider the normal bundles $N_{X/Y}\to X$ and $N_{Y/Z} \to Y$ and the normal bundle $N_{X/Z} \to X$ of the composition.

We know:

$N_{X/Z} \cong N_{X/Y} \oplus f^*N_{Y/Z}$ in this smooth setting, but the proof (as far as I know) uses splittings. To what extent does this work in the holomorphic category? Specifically, does this work for diagonal maps $\Delta: X \rightarrow X \times X$ and their iterative compositions? ($\Delta: X \times X \xrightarrow{id \times \Delta} X \times X \times X$ etc.)

Comment: In the holomorphic setting there is only (in general non-split) short exact sequence of normal bundles. But such a question would be more appropriate on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Blow up a point on a surface. The normal bundle of the projective line there will have a negative degree summand.

Embed the surface in a projective space. The normal bundle of the projective line there won't have a negative degree summand.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about how this answers the question?